# insertRowsAtIndexPaths index 3 beyond bounds at endUpdates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to make something like a NSFetchedResultsController with multiple queries. I'm planning to fetch the data and saving the results to NSArray. But whenever I try to scroll quickly the endUpdates raises an index 3 beyond bounds exception.

The following code is the code to add more people to the array. I'm calling this method when cellForRowAtIndexPath is called for the the last element. Please let me know if i'm doing anything wrong.

self.persons is my data source

```
    NSMutableArray *newPeople = [NSMutableArray new];

    NSArray *popular = [self fetchFewPopular];
    [newPeople addObjectsFromArray:popular];

    NSArray *randoms = [self fetchFewRandoms];
    [newPeople addObjectsFromArray:randoms];

    NSArray *reminders = [self fetchFewRandoms];
    [newPeople addObjectsFromArray:reminders];

    [self shuffleArray:newPeople];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    NSMutableArray *insertingRows = [NSMutableArray new];
    [self.persons addObjectsFromArray:newPeople];

    for (Person *newPerson in newPeople) {
        [insertingRows addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.persons indexOfObject:newPerson] inSection:0]];
    }
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertingRows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    for (Person*person in newPeople) {
        [self.personObjectIDS addObject:person.objectID];
    }
```

The Stack trace of the Exception:

> ```
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 ..
> ```
>
> 2]'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      __exceptionPreprocess + 165     1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   objc_exception_throw + 45     2   CoreFoundation
>   -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 227    3   UIKit
>   -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private)
>   _setupAnimationsForExistingVisibleCells] + 296    4   UIKit                               -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimations] + 151
>     5   UIKit
>   -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:] + 1812     6   UIKit                               -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] +
>   11935     7   Touchiq                             0x00

Comment: why do you use `@synchronized`? You should perform all UI operations on main thread only. Is there any chance that they are performed on a background thread?

Comment: Sorry that is being called from the main thread itself. Removed it from the question to make it clear..

Comment: And the code you posted is called directly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? And, last but not least - why don't you simply use `NSFetchedResultsController`? :)

Comment: It is in a method which gets called from cellForRowAtIndexPath, I'm planning to have multiple queries, can I do that with NSFetchedResultsController?

Comment: It depends on what your "multiple queries" are. The `NSFetchRequest` combined with `NSPredicate` is powerful and you can create really complex queries. But it's restricted to fetch only one entity (which should be enough for most use cases).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a good idea to add or remove rows in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. That's because this method is called by the table view when it is being updated / reloaded. So when you trigger another update in the middle of an ongoing one, weird things might happen.

A common practice is to use the method `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` to add new rows when the last cell is going to be displayed.

Or alternatively, use `scrollViewDidScroll` method (from `UIScrollViewDelegate`) because `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. Popular [SVPullToRefresh + SVInfiniteScrolling](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh) library uses this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to update your datasource between `[self.tableView beginUpdates];` and `[self.tableView endUpdates];`

Comment: Even if I change the data source in between beginUpdates and endUpdates I've the same problem. It did not make any difference. I've updated the question for the same.

Comment: Interesting. What if instead of doing beginUpdates, insertRowsAtIndexPaths, and endUpdates, you just call [self.tableView reloadData] after the datasource is updated?

Comment: I can do that.. But I don't want to reload the whole table view. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: TableViews are super-efficient. Calling reloadData would really only re-lay out the visible cells. But if you were worried about it, you should be able to just call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: on your table view.

Comment: The only problem with table reload is that the view does not get updated until the scroll is stopped. Hence the user has to wait until the scroll stops and then the new cells shows up. Can I do a reload cells before inserting it?